# c++ write to the beginning of current line of file

Tags: c++, file, line

I created a **ofstream file**.

How can I write to the beginning of current line on my file?

For example: I write:

```
a b c d e f
```

and now I want to add to the beginning the number of my letters (6) like this:

```
6 a b c d e f
```

Comment: And you tried what?

Comment: How did you write the first? How did you try to write the second and didn't work?

Comment: When writing text to file, you can append to the end or rewrite.  In order to append to the beginning, you have to come up with a creative way of using those two tools (rewriting/appending to end... and don't forget you can read files into memory).

Comment: An "ofstream file"? You mean you're writing a file using an ofstream? And have you already written "a b c d e f", or are you *about to* write something and you want to write "6 a b c d e f"?

Answer (score 2):

You have to read the whole file in a byte array.

Then you write your "prefix" followed by you write the byte array to a tmp file.

Finally you have to delete the original file and rename the tmp file.

If you want to write at the beginning of an arbitrary line then you should read the whole file in an array of arrays of bytes, append your prefix to the line you want to edit and finally overwrite the original file.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:-**

If it is a text file then the best solution would be to flush the old contents into a temporary location, write what you need and append the old contents

Comment: Because using `getline` and `std::string::operator+` on the first line is too mainstream.

Comment: @PawełStawarz:- Yes very correct..and If the original line has a fixed length, and you want to replace it, then all you have to do is open the file with both `ios_base::in and ios_base::out`.

Answer (score 0):

Files are pretty static and don't support adding characters anywhere except at the end. If you need to add characters elsewhere, you need to rewrite the file. Also, files don't really have a concept of lines.

What you *could* do is recording the position of the file at the beginning of the line (using `file.tellp()`), write a couple of placeholders (e.g., spaces), and then the rest of the line. Once the line is complete, you'd reposition the write position (using `file.seekp()`) and overwrite some of the placeholders.

Personally, I wouldn't do anything like that! Instead, I would format the line into a `std::ostringstream` and, once completed write the line start information followed by the firmatted line (obtained from the `std::ostringstream` using `str()`). Well, ideally I'd write the information in one sequence directly to the file if it is readily available.

Answer (score 0):

Files are essentially a stream of bytes that start at a specific location.  The only way to insert new data in the front (or in the middle) of a file is to move the data that is after it.  Since you are expecting to rewrite the first line, that would mean you would need to read the entire file, prepend your new data, and write out the entire (new) file over the existing one.  You can do this with a single `std::fstream` object, but you will need to reset the file cursor to the beginning after you read the file.  It would be more clear to read the file in using an `std::ifstream` object and then to overwrite the file with an `std::ofstream` object.

Answer (score 0):

I have on my code:

file << **args**;

-->here I want to add to the beggining of this line a new argument.. (This argument has information of **args** But I must write **args** and after I have the information for the argument)

file << endl;